# Vue 3 composition Api: V-For loop not accessing data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this template

My issue is that `location.drawnfeatures` in template is not updating for some reason
I can see I have the right data from `console.log` and I tested without `'v-for'` and the code works

if I put `v-if="location.drawnFeatures.length"` I get error saying length is not defined..

I tried adding `.value` about everywhere

Why is vue3 not accessing data ?

```
<ol-feature v-for="(feature, index) in location.drawnfeatures" :key="'feature'+uid+index">
  <ol-geom-point :coordinates="feature.coordinates"></ol-geom-point>
```

location is defined like this:

```
props:{
 locationData:Object,
},
setup(props){
  const location = ref({
    center:[0, 0],
    zoom:5,
    coordinates:null,
    rotation: 0,
    name:null,
    title:null,
  })

 onMounted(() => {
  location.value = props.locationData && props.locationData.location ? props.locationData.location : location.value
  console.log(location.value)
 });
}
```

I also tried declaring prop in `setup()`

`const locationData = toRef(props)`

if I do `console.log(locationData.value)` I get undefined

but this is not working either

Comment: That's likely because it's not initialy defined on your ref. I guess `drawnfeatures` comes from the prop you're passing and reasigning to the ref? Try to declare in as an empty array on your ref.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I added the prop section in my question.

Comment: I also just see the code accessing the `location.drawnfeatures` but I don't see the code where the `location.drawnfeatures` property is defined.

Comment: Where does a value of `locationData` prop comes from? Async Ajax call maybe? btw logging objects to browser console does not work [as you might expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects)

Comment: `location.drawnfeatures` is not a prop, `locationData` is

Comment: `locationData` is provided by the parent. I checked with the link provided and the data is good, even with `JSON.parse...`,

Comment: You didn't return anything from setup. Local variables like `location` cannot become available to the outer scope by magic, JS doesn't work like that. This is in conflict with "length is not defined" statement because the error would be different. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem and post the exact error, not retell it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why but this works: I had to stop using the prop directly and destructure `location`

first I had to declare in two places (don't ask me why)

```
props:{
  locationData:Object,
},
setup(props, context) {
  const locationData = toRef(props)
```

in `mounted` I did something like:

```
  if(props.locationData.location) {
    if(props.locationData.location.drawnFeatures) {
      locationFeatures.value = props.locationData.location.drawnFeatures
    }
    if(props.locationData.location.zoom) {
      zoom.value = props.locationData.location.zoom
    }
```

then transformed the property location into a method:

```
const location = () =>  { 
 return {
  center:center,
  drawnFeatures:drawnFeatures
}}
```

and modified the template

```
 <ol-feature v-for="(feature, index) in locationFeatures" :key="'feature'+uid+index">
    <ol-geom-point :coordinates="feature.coordinates"></ol-geom-point>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you destructure an object that you get via props, the destructured value will lose reactivity:

- https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#props

> However, because props are reactive, you cannot use ES6 destructuring because it will remove props reactivity.

It seems that with `location.value = props.locationData.location` you are accessing a nested object value from a prop and it does not maintain reactivity.

Based on the code it looks like it should be possible to use the `locationData` prop directly in the for loop:

```
<ol-feature v-for="(feature, index) in locationData.location.drawnfeatures" :key="'feature'+uid+index">
```

You can also set a default object in the props and you might not need to define the location in the setup.

```
props: {
 locationData: {
  type: Object,
  default() {
   return {
    location: {
     center: [0, 0],
     zoom: 5,
     coordinates: null,
     rotation: 0,
     name: null,
     title: null,
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried creating the prop in setup as added in my question; I also tried to create a new prop and just accessing it directly but it is not working; template is not updating

Comment: The question seems a bit confusing as it says in the beginning that using console.log it's possible to see that the data is correct but then later in the question using console.log(locationData.value) gives back undefined. If it's undefined v-for of course won't work. At what point in the code does the data exist as it should and can you provide an example object? (If there are any really long arrays then maybe an abbreviated sample)